# Show AlertDialog on Activity start, but not on screen orientation change?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

It seems when screen orientation changes, the activity's `onCreate()` method is called. In my `onCreate()` method, I have an `AlertDialog` which pops up when the activity is called. The problem is when I switch the screen sideways, the popup is displayed again.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `AndroidManifest` with:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Your `Activity` should look like this:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/my_activity_name"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
```

This will avoid the call to `onCreate()` when there is a change in the orientation.